# Gatsby Strapi does not load styles

Tags: gatsby, strapi

I have a **problem with loading styles** on my blog subpages (page is live, so you can see that here: https://vaire.pl/Dlaczego-smog-jest-szkodliwy).

This is how my page looks like when I enter specific blog post **via url** or I **refresh the page** instead of navigating there from main page (main page -> blog -> any blog post).

[image: gatsby styles are not loaded]

**What works**

When I navigate to the blog post from menu - styles are loaded.
But they were loaded previously, and are correctly passed to other component.

Surprisingly - styles start to load, **when I hover on a button** saying "Pozostałe wpisy" (it means "More blog posts"). I can see new request in network tab in developer tools which should be there in the first place. Below you can see how the page should look like.
[image: gatsby strapi finally loads css styles]

I use 'gatsby-source-strapi' plugin and 'gatsby-plugin-offline' which may cause this issue.
Do you have any ideas how to deal with that problem?

**My solutions:**

My first thought were that, it is about 'app-data.json' and 'page-data.json' request returning 404. However I found that it is how Gatsby is designed.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `gatsby-plugin-offline` as you said to check that is causing the issue?

Comment: I have not. Because if it is causing the issue, I still do not like giving up on this feature. However will try and let you know the results